# Spring Rest API - multiple threads

Tags: spring, rest

I have developed a Spring rest API that takes the Multipart file in the request and then uploading them to AWS S3 location. This process is taking time and the client has to wait for this whole process to be completed.

I do not want client to wait for this upload process to complete but I do want to send the image URLs in the response.

Can I just send the image URLs in the response and open a another thread for uploading the images to S3?

Comment: I would suggest having the users upload the files directly to S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it via Springs' [DeferredResult](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html) which leverages the Servlet 3.0 Async capabilities.

Your controller would look something like below (*originally posted [here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/03/deferredresult-asynchronous-processing.html) by [Tomasz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605744/tomasz-nurkiewicz)*)

```
@RequestMapping("/upload")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<String> upload() {
    final DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    runInOtherThread(deferredResult);
    return deferredResult;
}

private void runInOtherThread(DeferredResult<String> deferredResult) {
    // Call AWS S3 for upload and collect response
    deferredResult.setResult("File uploaded");
}
```

Refer tutorial for complete working example.